# asus 1215p cannot get the 1366 x 768 resolution

Tags: graphics-card, resolution, intel-graphics

I had a Windows 7 starter installed on this netbook, it wasn't that great so I installed Windows 7 Ultimate.

everything is OK apart from the screen resolution. it doesn't let me choose the optimal 1366x768 resolution and defaults to lower quality, in fact it doesn't even list it.

I have tried drivers from Microsoft, Asus and Intel and still no luck.

Any suggestions?

It has the `Intel 3150 Graphics Media Accelerator`.

Comment: I would like to add that i have tried the suggested removal of the intel driver and searching via windows but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the driver you need to install but I do have a work around. Use the Intel utility to set a custom resolution, make sure you set color depth and refresh rate:
[image]

You could also try going into device manager and uninstalling the monitor and video driver there, just right click and click uninstall then restart your computer. It's possible the person from the other thread used device manager and add/remove programs to uninstall the device.

Comment: cheers mate, worked a charm!